# NameError: name 'min_hash' is not defined

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-mining, minhash

My spark code out some error with min_hash. Just don't know what to do? Have to import some package? I'm a beginner so have to start with little steps...

[image: enter image description here showing]

Comment: Please use the "code sample" feature to show code snippets. Avoid sending screenshots.

Comment: I think code part that have the problem is not present on the screenshot. Seems like you're using variable/function that you didn't define/import.